# Partial Derivative-Chain Rule

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

If $F(v^2-x^2,v^2-y^2,v^2-z^2)=0$ and $v$ is a function of $x,y,z$. How to proof that $$\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{1}{y}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}+\frac{1}{z}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{z}}=\frac{1}{v}$$